# .exe keeps crashing, Open CV

Tags: opencv, compilation, crash

I keep having trouble with this simple code, which is supposed to open my camera but `.exe` keeps crashing. Any idea what should I do about this?

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    if(!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "No camera detected on this system" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while(true) {
        cap >> image;
        if(image.empty()) {
            cerr << "Frame invalid and skipped!" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        imshow("test", image);
        waitKey(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "crashing" and provide more details. Any error messages produced? Uncaught exceptions (use debugger). What platform? What OpenCV version? And so on...

Comment: http://pokit.org/get/?d01339bf574ea58660c91bb2a3c380d2.jpg   gcc 5.1.0, opencv 3.1.0

Comment: make sure all necessary dlls are available to the apl. Add a std::cout before each code line to see where it crashes.

Comment: Start by running it in debug mode, and not release. Debug mode is far more helpful for locating problems. And run the application step wise so you know which line is causing the problem.

Comment: it was run in debug mode, didn't show any problems